ToBool not found in fastrtps-2.14.dll
I have just installed ROS2 Jazzy on Windows 10 PC.
When I try to run turtlesim turtlesim_node, I get error complaining about
The procedure entry point "?ToBool#XMLUtil#tinyxml2@@SA_NPEDPEA_N@Z" is not found in the DLL "C:\opt\ros2\bin\fastrtps-2.14.dll"

But when I press OK the node runs correctly!
I get the same error when I try to run ros2 node list.
What could be the problem causing such error and how to correct it?
